# Failed in creating a directory

Tags: android, apk

I'm having problems with regards to creating a directory from an external storage, here is the method that I'm using.

```
public String createDir(String npath,String ndir,String file)
{
    String[] paths = new String[] { npath, npath + ndir };

    for (String path : paths) {
        File dir = new File(path);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.v(TAG, "ERROR: Creation of directory " + path + " on sdcard failed");
                return "ERROR: Creation of directory " + path + " on sdcard failed";
            } else {
                Log.v(TAG, "Created directory " + path + " on sdcard");
            }
        }

    }
    if (!(new File(npath + ndir + file)).exists()) {
        try {
            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            InputStream in = assetManager.open(ndir + file);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(npath + ndir + file);

            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            in.close();
            out.close();

            Log.v(TAG, "Copied " + file);
            return "Copied " + file;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Was unable to copy " + file + e.toString());
            return "Unable to copy " + file + e.toString();
        }
    }
    else
        return "Error!";
}
```

But I always get "ERROR: Creation of directory " + path + " on sdcard failed". Not to mention this is already installed in an android device. I tried looking for the directory of my application, but it is nowhere to be found, that supposedly, should be creating its folder automatically after the installation of my APK. Anyone who can resolve this?

Comment: do you have permission in the manifest? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: There should be some errors or warnings in LogCat. We need to see that in order to have an idea what is going on there. It can be Permission issue as @PedroBernardo said.